# Azure Factory v2 Wildcard

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake-gen2

I am trying to create a new dataset in ADF that looks for csv files that meet a certain naming convention. These files are located within a series of different folders in my Azure Blob Storage.

For instance, in the sample directory below, I am trying to pull out csv files that contain the word "cars".

```
Folder A 
    fastcars.csv 
    fasttrucks.csv
Folder B
   slowcars.csv
   slowtrucks.csv
```

Ideally , I would end up with the files "slowcars.csv" and "fastcars.csv". I've seen examples out there were people were able to wildcard the file name. I have been playing around with that, but have had no luck. (See image below for one example of what I have been doing).
[image: ee]

Is what I am trying to do even possible? Would appreciate any advice you guys may have. Please let me know if I can provide further clarification.

Comment: If you think my answer helps you,you could mark it.Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the description of filename in this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-data-lake-storage#dataset-properties),

> The file name under the given fileSystem + folderPath. If you want to
> use a wildcard to filter files, skip this setting and specify it in
> activity source settings.

so you need to specify it in activity not in file path.

A easy sample in copy activity:
[image]

Hope this can help you.